# Ignore system fields, audit Fields when Extracting fields of an specific object through describe call

Tags: apex

I am using describe call and getting all the fields of a specific object.

I dont want the system defined fields like (`Id`, `LastModifiedBy`, etc) in the final list which i will obtain through the describe call. I tried using `isCreateable()` & `isUpdateable()` of `Schema.DescribeFieldResult` class but got no success.

One way to do this is by removing the fields which i dont want from the list. But i want a dynamic way to do this.

Can anybody help me identify system and audit fields from list of fields using dynamic apex?

Answer (score 1):

From [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe):

> `isCustom()`
>
> Returns true if the field is a custom field, false if it is a standard field, such as Name.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing and unfortunately there's not an easy (and dynamic) way to do this as far as I know, so I ended up creating a set of blacklisted system fields that I know I didn't want and if the field API name showed up in the list when I was gathering fields via the Schema class I just ignored it. My final list ended up being:

```
private Set<String> blacklistedFields = new Set<String>{'CompletedDateTime','RecurrenceRegeneratedType','RecurrenceMonthOfYear','RecurrenceInstance','RecurrenceDayOfMonth','RecurrenceDayOfWeekMask','RecurrenceType','RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey','RecurrenceEndDateOnly','RecurrenceStartDateOnly  ','RecurrenceActivityId','ReminderDateTime','ActivityOriginType','ArchivedDate','IsArchived','IsClosed','PrioritySortOrder','IsHighPriority','AccountId','Jigsaw Contact Id','ReportsToName','EmailBouncedReason','EmailBouncedDate','IsEmailBounced','JigsawContactId','Id','IsDeleted','CreatedDate','LastModifiedDate','SystemModstamp','LastActivityDate','LastViewedDate','LastReferencedDate','UserRecordAccessId','MasterRecordId','AccountSource','IsCssEnabled','CssLastLoginDate','CompareName','PhotoUrl','CompareSite','OwnerAlias','JigSawCompanyId','ConnectionReceivedDate','ConnectionSentDate','AccountRollupId','ProductIsArchived'};
```

Very long, I know! It would really be nice if Salesforce had an easy way to get only fields that show up in the Object Manager.